# Widgets appearing late

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm building this program

```
def buffer():
    global buf
    frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebk, relief = RAISED)
    if buf==0:
        notebk.add(frame2, text = 'Buffer pH')
        notebk.select(frame2)
        buf=1
    else:
        notebk.select(frame2)
    import buffer
    buffer.main(frame2)
```

This part of the code is supposed to call another program I've written somewhere in a separate file on a new tab.

```
def main(x):  
    g=x
    op=Label(g,text="Hello") #...and so on
```

The program works but the widgets on the new tab appear either significantly late or after the window is configured in some way (moved/resized).

Any tips on how I can fix this?

Comment: We can't diagnose the problem if we can't reproduce it. Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Calling `widget.update()` or `widget.update_idletasks()` might possibly help, but I otherwise agree with Bryan.  (The latter has nothing to do with IDLE.)  If you use IDLE, read the IDLE doc section "Developing tkinter applications".